# Using enums with SpringBoot and Angular

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, enums

I would like to have field like task important and later make query using JPA to sort it according to task value. I do not know how to set enums with mysql, springboot and angular correctly so I came up with something like this: just add new column in database it would be String. Secondly, in Angular make

```
export enum Task_Weight {
    IMPORTANT = 'IMPORTANT',
    NOT_IMPORTANT = 'NOT_IMPORTANT'
}
```

Just make options that user can select. It should work, but now I have a problem. How can I write JPA query to sort all tasks according to Task_Weight? Maybe, I should do this in Angular?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always sort the data (JSON) fetched from back-end. All you need to do it to convert your data in an array and use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) (very rich JS utils framework library) to sort it in angular itself.

Example - let's assume you have an array like below:

`const arr = [ { id: 1, task_weight: 44 }, {id: 2, task_weight: 22}, { id: 3, task_weight: 55}]`

To sort this using `lodash` in angular component-

`import * as _ from 'lodash';
_.sort(arr, ['task_weight']);`